# Networks: how to model them using aggregate roots?

Tags: validation, transactions, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

A domain model defines a.o. the relationships between entities and we define aggregate roots to provide encapsulation and transaction boundaries. The well known relationships are one-to-one relationships (an entity or value object is contained within an aggregate root), one-to-many relationships (an aggregate root contains a collection of child objects) and many-to-many relationships. The latter are difficult, because many-to-many relationships between aggregate roots get you in trouble with the transaction boundary. Thus, in many cases, one direction of the many-to-many relationship is seen as more important and only that relation is modeled as a one-to-many relation.
Now, take it one step further. **Networks.** Many-to-many relationships between equivalent partners. **How can you model that without violating the transaction boundary on your aggregate roots?**
Have a look at this widely-applicable example:
I have a network with nodes. Every node has a limited amount of ports. One port can only be connected to one port on another node. I have to be able to add and remove connections between nodes, using the ports.
An intuitive approach to this would be to model the nodes as aggregate roots containing ports. Connections seem to be value objects and one port can have one connection. I could implement a Node.ConnectTo(nodeId, portId) method which add the connection (between port X on node A and port Y on node B) to the aggregate root, node A. Preferably, I would call this method twice, once on Node A and once on Node B and wrap it in a transaction. **However, this would violate the transaction boundary, so I decide to only store it on Node A.**
To see the connection on node B on the application client, a separate read model would be needed. But that's no problem, the CQRS architecture provides us these possibilities. So, adding, removing and viewing connections is not a problem.
The problem arises when I want to validate whether a port is still free before I add the connection to a port. The result of respecting our transaction boundary is that (in the write model) the fact that a port already is connected might not be known to the aggregate root, but might be stored in any other aggregate root.
Of course, you could trust your client's validation, go ahead and add the connection if it's ok for the node you are adding it to and rely on a process running consistency checks to execute compensating actions for invalid connections. But that seems to be a big deal to me compared to wrapping a transaction around two ConnectTo calls...
This made me think that **maybe my aggregate roots were chosen incorrectly**. And I started thinking about Nodes and Networks as aggregate roots, where a Network is a collection of Connections. The good thing about a Network aggregate is that you could always validate adding or removing connections. Except when a new connection would result in the joining of two existing networks... And your aggregate could become big, possibly resulting only in a single huge network. Not feasible either.
So, how do you think this should be modeled? **Do you see a solution where you respect aggregate roots as transaction boundaries, you can validate your network and you do not risk to store your entire network as a single aggregate?** Or am I asking for all 3 CAP's here and is it simply not possible?

Comment: you need to make your question more readable

Comment: See [FAQ How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and use the level formatting to help us reading and understanding your question.

Comment: Your reasoning about transaction boundaries seems a bit artificial ... Might be good to look at the roles within the system, who will be manipulating networks and nodes concurrently, and how fast each role requires feedback (maybe the entire thing can be validated offline and in sequence), or switch over to a more reservation oriented system (e.g. Lock nodes for a period of time and a certain operation). Don't forget to talk to the domain experts.

Comment: Yes Yves, you are right. The discussion written here is very artificial. It starts from relationships (one-to-many, many-to-many) instead of starting from consistency boundaries. Aggregates are about consistency, not about aggregation, which is the result of the encapsulation needed to create a consistency boundary. Consistency requirements are indeed determined by other things than the relations found in the model. That's where you need the domain experts. Maybe aggregates should be called 'Consistency Units' to make people think of consistency first instead of just parent-child relations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your "new way" is flawed, since the View model should not produce an Exception that propagates "somehow" back to the domain model. The domain model need to resolve this by itself.

So, in this case (bind 1-to-1) you could utilize events within the domain model, so that

1. NodeA.connect( "port1" ).to( NodeB ).on( "port3" );
2. NodeA reserves "port1" on itself.
3. NodeA sends a "portConnectionRequest" to NodeB.
4. NodeB binds "port3" if available.
5. NodeB sends "portConnectionConfirmed" or "portConnectionDenied".
6. NodeA receieves event and acts accordingly.

The above assumes reliable messaging, which is easily achieved within the JVM, but much harder in a distributed environment, yet that is where you want it more. If a reliable messaging system can not be provided, I think you will have a [Byzantine Agreement Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Agreement_Problem) problem at hand, or a subset of it.

Comment: Whenever "transactions are needed" pops up in your head, think "inter-bank money transfer". The "transaction supporters" always brings up bank transactions, yet there is no inter-bank 2phase commit, only eventual consistency.

Comment: You're right. The domain model must handle this itself. My solution was close (signaling the event from the view model), but is no way as clean as yours. And indeed, the BAP can be addressed by timing out the reservation. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I [read](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/) and thought some more about it and I guess this is the 'right' way to do it:

1. Before executing the ConnectTo method on Node A, you validate whether the port on Node B is still free using an eventually consistent view model as your data source (not the domain model which cannot validate this efficiently, see above).
2. ConnectTo is run only on Node A, thus no transaction boundary is violated.
3. If the view model is not able to connect the port on Node B, because it is already in use, a true concurrency exception has happened and it must be signaled. Some action needs to be taken (either manuel intervention or an automated process must pick it up). The probability for this concurrency exception will usually be very low.